# How to avoid "ModuleNotFoundError" when trying to export a pandas data frame to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have populated a data frame in a Jupyter Notebook and need a line of code to export the data frame to excel.

I have tried `df.to_excel('data.xlsx')` where `df` is my data frame.

The table is 25x10 but gives me an error when I type the mentioned line of code. The error I get is `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: You'll need to install whatever module it's complaining isn't installed on the system running your jupyter instance. Likely it's `xlsxwriter`, so `pip install xlsxwriter` or through conda or however you manage your python environment.

Comment: I bet it's `openpyxl`!

Comment: Only pandas module is required for this line of code. And this should be installed as you have constructed the DataFrame,

Comment: Your error message in Jupyter should show exactly which module is not found. Such as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unknown'`

Comment: Where will my file be saved? I am not getting an error anymore. I can't find where the excel file is being created/stored.

Answer (score -2):

why not try `df.to_csv('data.csv')` then open the CSV file with excel and save as .xlsx file?

Comment: `to_excel` takes the name of the file to be written to as an argument. It's in the docs. The OP usage is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).